# How to send data between two Raspberry Pis in two separate houses using TCP

Tags: python, tcp

So I'm trying to figure out how to send string data between two Pi Zero W units. I want one of them to be with me and one of them to be with one of my friends in her house. I'm really confused as to how this would work. I found a bit of code that seemed to work for both units in my house but, after changing the IP Address to my friend's public IP and trying to use it at her house, nothing came through. I'm fairly new to using internet protocols so any help would be appreciated.

**Send.py**

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = ''
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port 
{1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, 
PORT_NUMBER))

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )

while True:
    myMessage = input()
    mySocket.sendto(myMessage.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
sys.exit()
```

**Receive.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 128

hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Did you do any port forwarding on your/your friend's router?

Comment: You should probably learn TCP inside out before you try messing with UDP. It's much more complicated.

Comment: @FamousJameous I did set up port forwarding on mine but not hers.

Comment: Your question asks about TCP but your code requests UDP sockets.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Like I said Im new to this stuff and I really dont know where I can go to research it

Comment: It's probably expedient to check a router port forwarding tutorial, like https://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm. You may have a local IP address like 192.168.1.100, connecting a router which has a public IP address like 10.120.100.100. The configuration of your friend is similar. In this case, in order for your friend to connect to your port, say 5000, it's not sufficient to give her your local IP. You have to configure the router to forward your 192.168.1.100:5000 to the router's 10.120.100.100:5000 for example. Then your friend can find your program at 10.120.100.100:5000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to connect them together:

1. RPI that listens to incoming TCP connections (Receive.py) has to have firewall port open on RPI (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69123/how-to-open-a-port)
2. there has to be port open on your home router that connects your RPI to the ISP
3. your RPI cannot be behind provider's NAT network - sometimes, you can purchase a static IP address from your provider, that doesn't change or at least public IP address that dynamically changes in time.

You can check if you're behind NAT in router admin page, check if the IP that router got assigned from ISP is the same as your IP address that servers on the internet see. Do this query:

[https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip+address](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip%20address) )

If they're same, you're not behind ISP's NAT and problem is not probably there. If the're different, you share IP's with other ISP's customers and you cannot run your own server app that will expose it's port to the internet.

Comment: Thank you! So I am not under my ISP's NAT. I can see my public IP and it is the same as my routers. But my friends IP is under her ISP's NAT. So I'm guessing this way wont work. Is their anyway that I can send data between us that doesn't require us both to not be under our ISP's NATs? Or what are some ways that I could set this up?

Comment: You can run socket server that listens at your home and the friend's RPI will connect to yours, because you can initiate TCP stream from inside of NAT network  with no problem.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill look into that. Again like I said, Im very new to this so thank you